# Help needed formatting Doctrine Query in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

Can anyone tell me how to format the query below correctly in my controller.

Currently it gives me nothing in my FilteringSelect. However if I change it to >= I get back all the kennelIDs which is incorrect also but at least I'm getting something.

I've tested that the session variable is set and can confirm that there are kennels with the matching capacity.

```
 // Create autocomplete selection for the service of this booking
   public function  servkennelAction()
   {
    $sessionKennelBooking = new Zend_Session_Namespace('sessionKennelBooking');
    // disable layout and view rendering
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender(true);

// get list of grooming services for dogs from the table
 $qry= Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('PetManager_Model_Kennels k');

       //This should be set by default and narrows down the search criteria
        if(isset($sessionKennelBooking->numPets)){
            $b=(int)$sessionKennelBooking->numPets;                             
             $qry->addWhere('k.capacity = ?','$b');
            }

    $result=$qry->fetchArray();

   //generate and return JSON string using the primary key of the table
   $data = new Zend_Dojo_Data('kennelID',$result);
   echo $data->toJson();
}
```

Many thanks in Advance.

Graham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that addWhere condition is wrong. It has to be:

```
$qry->addWhere('k.capacity = ?', $b);
```

i.e. $b without quotes.